# How to add Toastr inside http catch function?

Tags: angular, toastr

I am having trouble trying to figure out how to have toastr inside my handlerError function. When I run it the error I receive is

> 'error' of undefined

Here is my code

```
private handlerError(error: any) {  

  var  errorMessage = 'Server error';

  this.toastrService.error(errorMessage); <-- This doesn't work

  return Observable.throw(errorMessage);
}
```

it is being called like

```
post(url, data): Observable<any> {     
    this.toastrService.error('hey'); // <-- This works
return this.http.post(CONSTANT.API_URL + url, data, {
  headers: this.createAuthorizationHeader()
}).
    map((res:Response) => { return this.toCamel(res.json()) }).
    catch(this.handlerError);
}
```

Toastr is being injected

```
constructor(private http: Http, private toastrService: ToastrService) {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
  catch(this.handlerError);
```

to

```
  catch(error => this.handlerError(error))
```

When you call like this.handlerError your this object in handlerError method is Window

When you do error => this.handlerError(error) - this error is ref you you class instance.

This is a standard javascript behaviour.

```
class A {
  classAContext() {
   return ()=>this.fn();
 }

 windowContext() {
   return this.fn;
  }

 fn() {
   console.log(this);
 }
}
```

let create a object:

```
let a = new A();
```

this line will print Window

```
 a.windowContext()();
```

this line will print A{}

```
 a.classAContext()();
```

Comment: that is so weird. Thanx

Comment: i added additional explanation